# Can I optimize this SQL query in any way?

Tags: t-sql

I have three tables called edum_application, edua_courseEvent and edua_coursePackage.

I'm writing a question to get all the applications from edum_application where all the courseEvent's coursePackage_id is x and all have the same applicationWrapper_id

This query works, but is it efficient?

```
SELECT app.application_id, app.applicationWrapper_id
FROM edum_application AS app
    INNER JOIN edua_courseEvent AS ce ON app.courseEvent_id = ce.courseEvent_id
WHERE app.applicationWrapper_id = 662
    AND app.courseEvent_id IN
    (
        -- Is this really efficient?
        SELECT ce.courseEvent_id
        FROM edua_courseEvent AS ce
        WHERE ce.coursePackage_id =
        (
            SELECT coursePackage_id
            FROM edua_courseEvent AS ce
            WHERE ce.courseEvent_id = 13377
        )
    )
```

The output:

```
application_id  applicationWrapper_id
72643           662
72645           662
72646           662
72647           662
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT     app.application_id, app.applicationWrapper_id
FROM       edum_application AS app
INNER JOIN edua_courseEvent AS ce
ON         app.courseEvent_id = ce.courseEvent_id
INNER JOIN edua_courseEvent AS ce2
ON         ce.coursePackage_id = ce2.coursePackage_id
WHERE      app.applicationWrapper_id = 662
AND        ce2.courseEvent_id = 13377
```

You might need a DISTINCT depending on the number of rows in / relationships between the different tables.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return any results as the code is broken. Also, I need not the distinct ones for a specific "wrapper" but all applications where the _courseEvents_ have the same _coursePackage_Id_, a value I don't know when I'm coming in to this query.

Comment: Awesome. This works great. I've also created an index on applicationWrapper_id as suggested in the Execution Plan. Thanks!